# Permitir valores negativos con máximo de dos decimales

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo la siguiente función que permite solo números enteros con máximo de dos decimales:

```js
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {

  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  var number = el.value.split(',');
  if (charCode != 44 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  //just one dot
  if (number.length > 1 && charCode == 44) {
    return false;
  }
  //get the carat position
  var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
  var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(",");
  if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 1)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function getSelectionStart(o) {
  if (o.createTextRange) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
    r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
    if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
    return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
  } else { return o.selectionStart }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control_normal" id="precio" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);"  >
```

Me gustaría que esta función me pudiera permitir valores negativos. ¿Qué debería agregar?

Comment: El código que pones no tiene nada de jQuery. Parece que estás usando JavaScript puro. Inicialmente quité la etiqueta de jQuery pero luego la volví a poner por si quieres una solución así

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que hacer 3 cambios sencillos en el código:

1. Permitir el carácter `-` (código 45)
2. Sólo permitir el `-` al principio del número
3. No permitir más de un `-`

Aquí te dejo los cambios comentados:

```js
function validateFloatKeyPress(el, evt) {

  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  var number = el.value.split(',');
  // permitir el signo de - (45)
  if (charCode != 45 && charCode != 44 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  //just one dot
  if (number.length > 1 && charCode == 44) {
    return false;
  }
  //get the carat position
  var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
  // no permitir que se ponega el - en una posicion diferente de la inicial
  if (caratPos > 0 && charCode == 45) {
    return false;
  }
  // no permtir mas de un - en el numero
  if (charCode == 45 && el.value.charAt(0) == "-") {
    return false;
  }
  var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(",");
  if (caratPos > dotPos && dotPos > -1 && (number[1].length > 1)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function getSelectionStart(o) {
  if (o.createTextRange) {
    var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
    r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
    if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
    return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
  } else { return o.selectionStart }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control_normal" id="precio" onkeypress="return validateFloatKeyPress(this,event);"  >
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería mostrar si el valor ingresado es correcto usando CSS. Además te ahorras mucho código.

**Ejemplo**

```js
let input = document.getElementById('val');
let valMsg = document.querySelector('input + .val-msg');

input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
 if(!input.checkValidity()) {
   valMsg.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
   valMsg.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
}
input:focus {
  border-color: #3498db;
  outline: none;
}
input:valid {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}
input:invalid {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}
.val-msg:after {
  color: red;
  content: attr(validation);
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Ubuntu', system;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    id="val" 
    pattern="^-?\d+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$" 
    required="required"
    title="Solo números con máximo 2 decimales"
   />
   <span class="val-msg" validation="Solo números con máximo 2 decimales"></span>
</form>
```

**Nota:** En el caso de IE, solo 10 o posterior.

Comment: aunque en las etiquetas no nombra css, buena respuesta

Comment: Pero pone la etiqueta html5, por lo que por ahí voy (HTML5 validation) jeje